# Function call yielded unexpected result

Tags: transistor

I've been experimenting with functions and upgrades, and it looks like this specific combination may not have been anticipated by the developers.

As you can see, the second slot currently has **Switch()** function upgraded by **Spark()** and **Help()**.

Function descriptions:

```
Switch() //   Active slot effect:
         // Alter a target's allegiance, causing it to serve the User.

Switch() + Help()  //   Upgrade slot effect:
                   //  Switch() will spawn a BadCell loyal to the User
                   // at the Target's location.

Switch() + Spark() //   Upgrade slot effect:
                   // Switch() will fan out multiple projectiles.
```

If we spawn a charged packet using **Load()** function and then hit it with our combo, we get BadCells spawned at every tick of the clock in all three directions. Is this an intended effect of this Function combination, or is it a bug?

Step 1: Spawn a volatile packet. Step 2: Strike with our combo function. (click for full resolution)

[image] [image]

And a Youtube video:

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that's a bug :) You should let the developers know, not us

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bug, I just spent the best part of an hour playing with it.

You do not need load to make this work, just having Switch(), with Spark() and Help() is enough. Hitting anything that actives switch will spawn BadCells like the pics/video you showed.

The way switch seems to work is very similar to a DOT. It applies the switch effect over time. Each tick of the switch DOT activates a BadCell Spawn. I can't get you any pics/video right now, so you'll have to trust me or try it without Load() for yourself.

I'll make sure that Supergiant are aware of it, but this isn't really a huge problem. It's not particularly easy to use very effectively in real combat, because it doesn't seem to work in Time() and you usually don't have enough time to set it up.

Comment: If you set Load() into passive slot, it will spawn enough packets to use this fast.

Comment: @user1306322 True, but you can choose not to get load() and you should be able to use the mass BadCells against the Sybil. I don't think you have to do any side areas either. No idea how effective it'd be though, I only realised how it worked after the Sybil fight.

Comment: @PenutReaper you get Help() from Sybil, so would be tricky to use it against her